# Group window instances when tabbing in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to group window instances when tabbing in windows 10?

E.g. the three windows framed in red are from the same application but are treated by windows as individual application windows. I'd like to group them and show all of them when switching between apps.

[image]

Comment: Unclear: How would you switch to a group?

Comment: I have read the post. If I asked a question, it's because your post is not very clear on the details.